# Visual Studio see list of all #regions in file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I am working on a file full of several tests, separated by #regions.

In Both VS 2022 and 2019, there's a nice dropdown in the top right that you can click that gives you a list of all the symbols in the file (properties, methods, constructors, etc.)

[image: Symbol List dropdown VS 2022]

This same list is also available in Solution Explorer, if you expand the file name and then the class name.

[image: Class Symbol List in Solution Explorer VS 2022]

---

However, I cannot find any such list anywhere in Visual Studio that gives a list of the #regions within a file. In a very large file that is intentionally segmented with #regions, it would be useful to see the list of all the regions so I can quickly move through sections of the code, instead of having to scroll through to find regions, or collapse all regions.

I can use Ctrl+T to Go to whatever I want, **except regions.**

**Surely there's a way for me to see a list of all #regions within a file or class, just like I can see all the symbols within a file or class?**

I have not been able to find an answer to this simple question, and it doesn't seem to have been asked anywhere. My searches on google (rather annoyingly) only yield results about how to collapse/expand regions, but nothing about seeing all of them.

---

And before someone says, "Just use partial classes if your class needs to be that big", even if I use partial classes (which I am already doing, to be fair), Ctrl+T and the Symbols List still show symbols across *all parts of the class,* so it would still be useful for this to include #regions.

Comment: Instead of a partial class, would using nested classes help?

Comment: Partial classes *are* a solution - instead of looking at the Symbols list, look at the member nodes that appear under a file in Solution Explorer. As far as symbols are concerned, there are no regions. Regions are purely a *text* organization feature. There may be a way to organize members based on attributes though

Comment: Unlike classes, regions are not part of the application's structure. They are just there for convenience (or inconvenience in my opinion). A well-structured class hierarchy shouldn't need them.

Comment: The [Category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute is used by the Property Viewer to group properties. The attribute can be applied to any member. I don't know if it affects the member list in Solutions Explorer though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so from what I understand, you are saying I just need to create _more_ partial classes?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your code is wrapped in #regions you can use the built-in feature to Collapse to Definition Ctrl + M , O. Then navigate to the region you want. You can undo the collapse by using Ctrl + M , P

**Edit: First, check in VS options if collapse regions is enabled. The path is:
Tools > Options > Text Editors > C# > Advanced > Check "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions"**

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for!